# How to find factorial bounds for a power of 2 quantity

Tags: factorial

I'm trying to find the integer $n$ such that

$$
n! \leq 2^k-1 \leq (n+1)!
$$

In particular for $k = 19937$

Wolfram Alpha [choked on it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve(factorial(x)%3D2%5E19937-1,x)), but I've got a feeling there is a trick somewhere to compute this.

Comment: For $k = 19937$, $n = 2080$. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%5E(19937)-1+)-+2081! and  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%5E(19937)-1+)-+2080!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a reasonable bound for $\log(n!)$, and by Stirling's inequality
$$ n\log n-n+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi n)+\frac{1}{12n+1}\leq\log(n!) \leq n\log n-n+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi n)+\frac{1}{12n} $$
so it is enough to solve
$$ \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log n-n = k\log2-\log\sqrt{2\pi} $$
through Newton's method with starting point $n_0=\frac{k\log 2}{\log k}$.
If $k=19937$, with just a couple of iterations we get $n=2080$.